# Zip scikit-learn datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run the following code snippet from a tutorial in python 3.3:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn import datasets
>>> iris = datasets.load_iris()
>>> np.array(zip(iris.data, iris.target))[0:10]
```

In 2.7 it returns the following output:

```
array([[array([ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 5.4,  3.9,  1.7,  0.4]), 0],
   [array([ 4.6,  3.4,  1.4,  0.3]), 0],
   [array([ 5. ,  3.4,  1.5,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 4.4,  2.9,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
   [array([ 4.9,  3.1,  1.5,  0.1]), 0]], dtype=object)
```

But in 3.3 it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: 0-dimensional arrays can't be indexed
```

I'm new to python and I know there are differences between 2.x and 3.x, I think this is simply in relation to the differences in print function, but I'd appreciate an explanation of what's happening here and how I can get it to run in 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that zip now returns an iterable rather than a list so you need to convert to a list first:

```
In [194]:

np.array(list(zip(iris.data, iris.target)))[0:10]
Out[194]:
array([[array([ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 5.4,  3.9,  1.7,  0.4]), 0],
       [array([ 4.6,  3.4,  1.4,  0.3]), 0],
       [array([ 5. ,  3.4,  1.5,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 4.4,  2.9,  1.4,  0.2]), 0],
       [array([ 4.9,  3.1,  1.5,  0.1]), 0]], dtype=object)
```

The behaviour of [zip](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html#zip) changed in python 3, note I get a different error to you when I ran your code:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-193-ec320a0afa3a> in <module>()
          2 from sklearn import datasets
          3 iris = datasets.load_iris()
    ----> 4 np.array(zip(iris.data, iris.target))[0:10]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Also there is more than just [print](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) that has changed in python 3.

Comment: Thank you. I do realize there was more that had changed than print but what I meant was my limited knowledge of those changes wasn't enough to help me see what other changes would be affecting this snippet. If you don't mind elaborating, why did you get a different error than I did? Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm running python 3.4 numpy 1.9.1, sklearn version 0.15.2 other than that it's because what has been created in my code is an array with one entry which is the zip object rather than the contents of the zip object